# How to deploy Angular, Nodejs & Mysql web app to heroku?

Tags: mysql, node.js, angular, heroku, deployment

I have my back-end server written on Nodejs (Express) and front-end on angular4 which consumes back-end apis. I used db Mysql. My back-end Nodejs server folder structure is like this

[image]

How can i deploy my complete application (Front-End + Back-End +DB) fully functional on heroku?

Comment: Welcome to SO.  If any of the given answers satisfy your question, mark the green answer button

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have the hosting account you need the following.

1. Set up DNS for your website

   https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/custom-domains
2. Heroku, create the the database and users names for it with password and put that in your application.  (I think they ask you to use MySQL provider - see link

   https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-mysql
3. Transfer your files to your Heroku site/account by using SFTP or git 
   If all of those are done correctly, then you should be able to reach your site publicly.

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/transferring-apps